# Measuring Application Performance

Tags: performance, performancecounter

I was wondering if there is a tool to keep track of application performance. What I have in mind is a tool that will listen for updates and register performance metrics published by an application. i.e. time to serve a request, time a certain operation took to finish. And this tool would then aggregate the data and measure performance trends.

Comment: This type of tool is called a profiler.

Comment: Some info regarding platform/language would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to measure your application from outside, then you can use [RRDtool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRDtool) to collect the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use slamd for webapp written in Java.
For Django use hotshot.

Search for profiler + your language, framework

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at HP SiteScope.  It's ability to drive the system with a Web User Script, to monitor the metrics on the backend, even to the extent of creation of custom shell scripts and database queries, plus the ability to add logic for report/alert against these combined data sets appears to be what you need.

Other mechanisms that you might consider would be a roll your own service using CURL to push information in, queries to the systems involved to pull metrics or database information and then your own interface for alerting and reporting.

Then it becomes a cost question, can you roll the level of functionality for less money than you can purchase an already existing solution on the open market.

Ref:
[HP SiteScope Wiki Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_SiteScope)